# How to combine the two results I got from for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm using Python Pyramid with MongoDB. When I selected multiple images, it will save the image name into session. On the confirmation page, I will retrieve the image name from the session and thus get the image pathname from the database.

this is what I have right now in Views.py

```
session = request.session
greet_array = session['selectgreetings'].split(",")
greet = GreetingsImg(request)  

print("session['selectgreetings']: " , greet_array)

for g in greet_array:
    print('g: ' , g)
    greetall = greet.get_by_name(g)

    for ga in greetall:
        greet_path = ga['path_name']
        print('path: ', greet_path)

return {'greet_path':greet_path}
```

if I do this, it will print this results (Command Prompt)

```
session['selectgreetings']:  ['Pics3', 'Pics2']
g:  Pics3
path:  static/image/greeting/03.jpg
g:  Pics2
path:  static/image/greeting/02.jpg
```

I was trying to combine the two paths so that I can get this in Command Prompt:

```
static/image/greeting/03.jpg, static/image/greeting/02.jpg
```

When I get the result above, I can use for loop in jinja2 to show the image selected:

```
{% for a in greet_path %}
<img src="/{{a}}" class="col-sm-5"/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You can append them to a single list. Try doing `new_list.append(ga['path_name']) for ga in greetall`

Comment: One little thing: the `return` keyword can only be used within functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the contents of an array into a string, with each element separated by a comma, by doing this:

```
", ".join(greet_path)
```